How to extract valuable information from the JSON output of Document AI custom extractors?
I am working with a simple custom extractor in Document AI, which tries to find the following fields in any pdf uploaded:
Country
Nombre
Adress
Country
Mail
Adress
City
And i am using the following code to extract the info and print the output JSON.
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai
import json
import os
from google.colab import files

# Credentials setup (assuming you've uploaded the service account key)
uploaded = files.upload()
key_file = list(uploaded.keys())[0]
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = key_file

# Configuration
PROJECT_ID = "682656916911"  # Replace with your project ID
LOCATION = "eu"  # Use the correct region
PROCESSOR_ID = "da26d6ce1aa73a53"  # Replace with your processor ID
DOCUMENT_PATH = "/content/W-8BEN.pdf"  # Path to your document

# Client setup
client_options = {"api_endpoint": "eu-documentai.googleapis.com"}
client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=client_options)

# Request preparation
name = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{LOCATION}/processors/{PROCESSOR_ID}"
with open(DOCUMENT_PATH, "rb") as document_file:
    document_content = document_file.read()

request = {
    "name": name,
    "raw_document": {
        "content": document_content,
        "mime_type": "application/pdf"
    }
}

# Process document
response = client.process_document(request=request)

# Print response and extracted text
print(f"Response type: {type(response)}")
print(f"Document type: {type(response.document)}")

if document := response.document:  # Use walrus operator for cleaner assignment
    print("\nExtracted text:")
    print(document.text)

    # Convert Document object to dictionary (avoiding DESCRIPTOR field)
    document_dict = documentai.Document.to_dict(document)
    print("\nJSON representation of extracted data (excluding DESCRIPTOR):")
    print(json.dumps(document_dict, indent=4))

However, the output JSON is useless to me. There are only coordinates and lot of noise and unwanted info. Here is just a fragment of it:
{
                    "layout": {
                        "text_anchor": {
                            "text_segments": [
                                {
                                    "start_index": "4392",
                                    "end_index": "4396"
                                }
                            ],
                            "content": ""
                        },
                        "confidence": 0.98868006,
                        "bounding_poly": {
                            "vertices": [
                                {
                                    "x": 522,
                                    "y": 1972
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 549,
                                    "y": 1972
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 549,
                                    "y": 1994
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 522,
                                    "y": 1994
                                }
                            ],
                            "normalized_vertices": [
                                {
                                    "x": 0.29692832,
                                    "y": 0.8668132
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 0.31228667,
                                    "y": 0.8668132
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 0.31228667,
                                    "y": 0.8764835
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": 0.29692832,
                                    "y": 0.8764835
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "orientation": 1
                    },
                    "detected_break": {
                        "type_": 1
                    },
                    "detected_languages": [
                        {
                            "language_code": "en",
                            "confidence": 1.0
                        }
                    ]
                },

I have tried to filter the fields that i want, but i am not able to get it done. I want to be able to see the pair key - value to validate or not the pdf uploaded, and reduce all that noise.
Thank you in advance.

Here are the examples of step by step guides on how to extract the form key/value pairs in a certain Document AI custom extractors. Specifically in step 7 of Managing Document AI processors with Python you will be guided to create utility functions to print out the detected form fields as well as in step 9 of this codelabs of Use Document AI to Intelligently Process your Handwritten Forms (Node.js).
